# Reload app in real device

Tags: react-native

I got information on my screen after run 1st project ReactNative:

> Double tap R on your keyboard to reload
>
> Shake or press menu button for dev menu

But how to do that on real device ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a real device, you juste have to:

> Shake or press menu button for dev menu

Shake device will make the dev menu appear.

Comment: this do not work on my tablet, is there other way for show this dev menu ?

Comment: Well, that's weird. On some devices, you can long press on the menu button or the bottom left button. You can also try `adb shell input keyevent 82`according to this link: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#accessing-the-in-app-developer-menu (never tested it by myself)